# Returning a column with node-mysql (like fetchColumn in PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, pdo, node-mysql

Is there any way to return a single column with [node-mysql](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql)? I'm looking for something analogous to `fetchColumn` in [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

For example, say I have the following query:

```
database.query("SELECT id FROM user", function(error, row) {
  console.log(row);
});
```

This would result in:

```
[{id: 1}, {id: 2}, {id: 3}, ...]
```

Instead, I would like:

```
[1, 2, 3, ...]
```

I can run a loop to extract the data, which is what I've been doing, but I find this coming up time and again so I'm wondering if there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably add your own function to the database class in an elegant way, but since Javascript has functional support, a non intrusive way would be to just wrap your function receiving the results in a wrapper function that removes the key;

```js
single_value = function(fn) {
  return function(e,r) {
    for(var k in r)
      break;
    return fn(e, k === undefined ? undefined : r[k]);
  }
}
```

That way, you can call the normal query function as;

```
database.query("SELECT id FROM user", single_value(function(error, row) {
  console.log(row);
}));

1
2
3
...
```